Access trackpad mutli-touch fingers as touch events in a web application
Almost all laptops these days with trackpad support multi-touch gestures. But I am unable to find a way to access trackpad touches through multi-touch events in browsers. It seems that only touchscreens make multi-touch events while trackpads (despite supporting multi-touch gestures) do not and browsers instead interpret gestures on their own, mapping them to various actions (scrolling, zooming, etc.).
Is there a way to request from browsers to pass trackpad multi-touch events as-is to a web application?
I am interested in how to do support this on Linux, Windows and Mac, if possible.
